# Android background not filling screen

Tags: android, background-image

I have an app with a tabHost; on one of the tabs I have an image for the background, but the image is not filling the whole screen:

[image: bgnd image]

My image is 480 x 800 px

my home.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/home_bgnd">
</LinearLayout>
```

How do I fix this code so I'll have the image covering the whole screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using tabhost in that case you have to look into your xml layout in which you have tabhost.

check for padding in view containing `android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"` and remove that padding or margin from there.

Answer (score 1):

Use ImageView in your XML and set `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to make it stretch to its parent layout. As parent layout, I would suggest you to use `FrameLayout` so the image can act as background to it.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/your_source"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- your other views here -->

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```